# Nodejs stream CSV, create table in postgres and import using COPY FROM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv

Is there a good way to put a large CSV (4GB+) in stream form into a postgres db in NodeJS?

In particular, I want to take the first line (a header line) and craft a create query off of that. I'd then like to stream the rest of the file to a copy from statement.

This would be doable if I just wanted to send to the copy command, for example:

```
function copyStreamIntoTable (inputStream) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  pg.connect("pg://postgres@localhost/npi_demo", function (err, client) {
    var s = client.copyFrom("COPY hptc (code, type, classification, specialization, definition, notes) FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER");

    inputStream.pipe(through(function (data) {
      this.queue(data.toString("ascii"));
    })).pipe(s).on('close', function () {
      deferred.resolve();
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

But I'd like the stream to have the first line read and then run a create query. Once the create query is complete, id like to stream the remainder of the stream to copyFrom.

Is there an elegant way to do this? I'm still a relatively new person to nodejs and streams.

Comment: Check to see if node.js's PostgreSQL interface has explicit support for `COPY` in its API. You'll want to use any such support if possible, rather than attempting to use the `COPY` statement directly.

Comment: As a side note, I'm super confused by streams in node ... I understand I could read the first line using something like readline ... and i could probably write the rest of it to the postgres stream using readline ... but in order to properly respect the backpressure applied by pg things seem to get much more complicated quickly unless i use pipe

Comment: @MichaelWasser hey i am new to node and i have same problem can you send me the code or little  more explain about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a more generalized answer to my question:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    through = require('through'),
    split = require('split');

var inFile = fs.createReadStream('./lines'),
    outFile = fs.createWriteStream('./out'),
    headers;

var th = through(function (data) {
  if (typeof headers === "undefined") {
    headers = data;
    th.pause();
    setTimeout(function () { th.resume(); }, 5000);
  } else {
    this.queue(data + "\n");
  }
});

inFile.pipe(split())
  .pipe(th)
  .pipe(outFile)
  .on("close", function () {
    console.log("had headers: " + headers);
  });
```

Where through and split are the npm-installed stream helpers.

If the contents of the inFile are:

```
one
two
three
```

the output will be `had headers: one` and the outFile will have the contents

```
two
three
```

In the context of my specific question -- the timeout would be replaced by querying the db to create the table and writing to the out file would be replaced to writing to the copyFrom stream.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you know if there are any recommendations as to the size of the CSV? Did you break up your file into several csv strings or just one? Any recos?

Comment: Nothing specific in terms of splitting it up -- I was importing a 4.5GB csv using this method